# Creating AJAX registration form

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, forms

I created a registration form following an online tutorial.

The current code doesn't insert anything into a database yet. I am just trying to get the basic error messages working.

When the form is submitted the error message "There was an error" is shown. This comes from my action page where the register button has been pressed.

I am not sure what has caused this.

I know there is a lot of code.

Any help is appreciated.

Main Page(With my form):

```
<head>
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script>
          $(document).ready(function(){
              $("form").submit(function(event){
                  event.preventDefault();
                  var forename = $("#txtfirstname").val();
                  var surname = $("#txtsurname").val();
                  var username = $("#txtusername").val();
                  var password = $("#txtpassword").val();

                  $(".form-message").load("aregisteraction.php", {
                      forename : forename,
                      surname : surname,
                      username : username,
                      password : password
                  });
              });
          });
      </script>
  </head>
  <body>
 <?php
 require 'leftnav.php';
  ?>
  <div class="two-thirds column">

    <h1> Not Registered?</h1>
    <h3>Register</h3>
    <form method="post" action="aregisteraction.php">      
    <p>
    <label for="txtfirstname" >Firstname: </label> </br>
    <input type="text" name="firstname" id="txtfirstname" />
    </p>
    <p>
    <label for="txtsurname" >Surname: </label> </br>
    <input type="text" name="surname" id="txtsurname" />
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for="ddage" >Age: </label> </br>
        <select name="ddage">
        <option value="0">Select a value</option>
        <option value="1">0-10</option>
        <option value="2">11-30</option>
        <option value="3">31-50</option>
        <option value="4">51-70</option>
        <option value="4">71+</option>
        </select>
    </p>
    <p>  
    <label  >Gender: </label> </br>
    <input type="radio" name="gender" value="male"> Male<br>
    <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female"> Female<br>
    </p>
    <p>
    <label for="txtusername" >Email: </label> </br>
    <input type="text" name="username" id="txtusername" />
    </p>
    <p>
    <label for="txtpassword" >Password: </label> </br>
    <input type="password" name="password" id="txtpassword" />
    </p>
    <p>
    <label for="txtpassword1" >Re-enter Password: </label> </br>
    <input type="password" name="password1" id="txtpassword1" />
    </p>
    <input type="submit" name="register" value="Register" />
    <p class="form-message"></p>
</form>
```

Action Page:

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['register'])){

   $forename = $_POST['forename'];
   $surname = $_POST['surname'];
   $username = $_POST['username'];
   $password = $_POST['password'];

   $errorEmpty = false;
   $errorEmail = false;       
if(empty($forename)||empty($surname)||empty($username)||empty($password)){
       echo "<span> Fill in all fields </span>";
       $errorEmpty = true;
   }
    elseif (!filter_var($username, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        echo "<span class='form-error'> Fill in a valid email </span>";
        $errorEmail = true;
    }
    else{
        echo "<span class='form-success'> Success </span>";
    }
}
else{
    echo "There was an error!";
}
?>
<script>
    $("#txtfirstname, #txtsurname, #txtusername, #txtpassword").removeClass("input-error");

    var errorEmpty ="<?php echo $errorEmpty; ?>";
    var errorEmail ="<?php echo $errorEmail; ?>";

    if(errorEmpty == true){
        $("#txtfirstname, #txtsurname, #txtusername, #txtpassword").addClass("input-error");
    }
     if(errorEmail == true){
         $("#txtusername").addClass("input-error");
         }
    if(errorEmail == false && errorEmpty == false){
        $("#txtfirstname, #txtsurname, #txtusername, #txtpassword").val("");
    }
    </script>
```

Comment: you are not posting the register value, and `isset($_POST['register'])` is returning false

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your JavaScript you doesn't send any value for *register*.

Two options: add a value to register:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("form").submit(function(event){
      event.preventDefault();
      var forename = $("#txtfirstname").val();
      var surname = $("#txtsurname").val();
      var username = $("#txtusername").val();
      var password = $("#txtpassword").val();

      $(".form-message").load("aregisteraction.php", {
         forename : forename,
         surname : surname,
         username : username,
         password : password,
         register: "ok",
      });

   });
});
```

Or simply test $_POST on another field (as register is a button and will always contains a value in the form).

Also, to test values of your form in PHP you can user **print_r()**:

```
print_r($_POST);
```